# Android Post_Method Json Array Response 500

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I created the functions like the json file in the picture. When I send a post request, the response is "Unexpected response code 500" for. I think the problem is caused by json arrays, I don't understand exactly why this error is coming. Server url works fine, successfully post on swift. Thanks

[json_array_requested_from_me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h21RV.png)

```
private void CreditCardParams(Map<String, String> requestParameters) {
JSONArray creditCardItems = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item_creditCardItems = new JSONObject();
try {
    item_creditCardItems.put("CC_NUMBER", "1111");
    item_creditCardItems.put("EXP_MONTH", “11”);
    item_creditCardItems.put("EXP_YEAR", “1111");
    item_creditCardItems.put("CC_CVV", “111”);
    item_creditCardItems.put("CC_OWNER", “TEST USER”);
    item_creditCardItems.put("INSTALLMENT_NUMBER", "1");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
creditCardItems.put(item_creditCardItems);
requestParameters.put("CreditCard", (creditCardItems.toString()));
```

}

```
private void CustomerParams(Map<String, String> requestParameters) {
JSONArray CustomerItems = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item_Customer = new JSONObject();
try {
    item_Customer.put("FIRST_NAME", "Firstname");
    item_Customer.put("LAST_NAME", "Lastname");
    item_Customer.put("MAIL", "test@test.com");
    item_Customer.put("PHONE", "+11111111");
    item_Customer.put("CITY", "Test");
    item_Customer.put("STATE", "Test");
    item_Customer.put("ADDRESS", "Test");
    item_Customer.put("CLIENT_IP", "111.11.11.11”);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

CustomerItems.put(item_Customer);
requestParameters.put("Customer", (CustomerItems.toString()));
```

}

```
private void ProductParams(Map<String, String> requestParameters) {
JSONArray ProductItems = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item_Product = new JSONObject();
try {
    item_Product.put("PRODUCT_ID", "1");
    item_Product.put("PRODUCT_NAME", “1”);
    item_Product.put("PRODUCT_CATEGORY", “Elec.”);
    item_Product.put("PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION", “Info”);
    item_Product.put("PRODUCT_AMOUNT", 15.00);     
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ProductItems.put(item_Product);
requestParameters.put("Product", (ProductItems.toString()));
```

}

```
private void ConfigParams(Map<String, String> requestParameters) {
  JSONArray configItems = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
try {
    item.put("MERCHANT", "TEST1234");
    item.put("MERCHANT_KEY", “123”);
    item.put("BACK_URL", "localhost");
    item.put("PRICES_CURRENCY", "USD");
    item.put("ORDER_REF_NUMBER", "RFN0001");
    item.put("ORDER_AMOUNT", 15.00);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
configItems.put(item);
requestParameters.put("Config", (configItems.toString()));
```

}

```
    private void post_func(){
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        CreditCardParams(params);
        CustomerParams(params);
        ProductParams(params);
        ConfigParams(params);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

Comment: A 500 answer means something unexpected happened in the server. To understand what went wrong we need more information. Does this request work on postman? What is the server expecting in terms of dataTypes?

Comment: I converted my parameter functions (CreditCardParams, ConfigParams...) to new json params, the response is successful. But I don't understand this solution.

New json parameters=>
   jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\n" +
                      " \"Configuration\" : {\n" +
                      " \"SELLER\" : \"TEST1234\",\n" +
...
}})

Answer (score 0):

As you know, 500 server error is an error caused by an exception in the server. If you don't get an error when you send the JSON file you showed from an http request sender program like postman, the problem is in the JSON object you sent to the server.

Comment: Yes I think so, but where is my mistake, I can't find it in my code block.